# How to Merge two Json files into one using C++?

Tags: c++, json, jsoncpp

I have 2 Json files having 100,000 records and 5 columns each.
My goal is to merge both files to get a single file with 200k records using C++.

My json files look like this:

```
[ 
    { 
    "city":"Lisbon",
    "name":"Shannon Ward",
    "job":"Ambulatory Nurse",
    "email":"Shannon_Ward6180@6ijur.works",
    "salary":"2308593.84555454"
    },
    { 
    "city":"Lancaster",
    "name":"Kurt Hopkinson",
    "job":"Lecturer",
    "email":"Kurt_Hopkinson235@nb44i.digital",
    "salary":"8564088.47550575"
    },
    { 
    "city":"Glendale",
    "name":"John Yates",
    "job":"Accountant",
    "email":"John_Yates1660@gkvds.store",
    "salary":"9003114.81075051"
    },
    { 
    "city":"Sacramento",
    "name":"Camila Wallace",
    "job":"Budget Analyst",
    "email":"Camila_Wallace8030@3wbkp.site",
    "salary":"1287392.46738351"
    }
]
```

which is basically an array holding structure (or map).

I am using [JsonCpp](https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp) library .

What I have tried:

```
Json::Value records1; 
Json::Value records2;

Json::Reader reader;  

reader.parse(file1, records1);    //file1 is input stream from 1st json file
reader.parse(file2, records2);    //file2 is input stream from 2nd json file

for (auto& itr : records2)
    records1.append(itr);
```

So, basically I am parsing json data from both files into Json::Value objects, and then later trying to append 1 object with elements of other object 1 by 1.

But, It's not working and compiler is giving this error:

> C++ no instance of overloaded function matches the argument list and object (the object has type qualifiers that prevent a match)
> argument types are: (const Json::Value)
> object type is: const Json::Value

Please let me know what I am doing wrong or what's the right approach to append 2 json files in C++

Comment: They aren't objects but references.

Comment: `const Json::Value& records1;` is not valid C++. References cannot be defined like that, in C++. Additionally, what you're doing wrong is failing to meet Stackoverflow's requirements for showing a [mre].

Comment: `const Json::Value& records1;` did that really compile? Having a non initialized ref is wrong code. Next is that is const and I expect that `parse` should modify it. And why the records are parsed into two instances instead reading simply both into one.... far away from working code I believe.

Comment: `const Json::Value& records1;`  -> `Json::Value records1; `

Comment: @john Thankyou very much, I myself got confused and created a reference instead of object

Comment: I think it would be easier to do with QT libs as:
<QJsonObject>
<QJsonArray>
<QTextStream>
<QJsonDocument>
or `boost` libs.
anyway maybe try to write the first into a file and then the second.
        QString jsonStr1 = QTextStream(&file1).readAll();
        QString jsonStr2 = QTextStream(&file2).readAll();
        file1.close();
        file2.close();
        /**write to file3**/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you're really set on using jsoncpp, I'd consider using [ThorSerializer](https://github.com/Loki-Astari/ThorsSerializer) (installable via brew) library instead. For a quick demo:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <string>

#include "ThorSerialize/JsonThor.h"

using namespace std::string_literals;

std::stringstream a( R"(
[
    {
        "city":"Lisbon",
        "name":"Shannon Ward",
        "job":"Ambulatory Nurse",
        "email":"Shannon_Ward6180@6ijur.works",
        "salary":"2308593.84555454"
    },
    {
        "city":"Lancaster",
        "name":"Kurt Hopkinson",
        "job":"Lecturer",
        "email":"Kurt_Hopkinson235@nb44i.digital",
        "salary":"8564088.47550575"
    }
]
)"s);

std::stringstream b( R"(
[
    {
        "city":"Glendale",
        "name":"John Yates",
        "job":"Accountant",
        "email":"John_Yates1660@gkvds.store",
        "salary":"9003114.81075051"
    },
    {
        "city":"Sacramento",
        "name":"Camila Wallace",
        "job":"Budget Analyst",
        "email":"Camila_Wallace8030@3wbkp.site",
        "salary":"1287392.46738351"
    }
])"s);

int main() {

    using ThorsAnvil::Serialize::jsonImporter;
    using ThorsAnvil::Serialize::jsonExporter;

    std::vector<std::map<std::string, std::string>> data;

    a >> jsonImporter(data);
    b >> jsonImporter(data);

    std::cout << jsonExporter(data) << "\n";
}
```

The advantage of ThorsSerializer over other libraries is that it parses data directly into the C++ types that you are using, rather than into a generic JSON like structure that must then be iterated over to convert into your C++ types.

All the standard types and containers are handled by default. There is no code declaration style used to add new user defined types.

Example [parsing JSON into C++ class](https://github.com/Loki-Astari/ThorsSerializer/blob/master/doc/example1.cpp).

Answer (score 4):

Unless you're really set on using jsoncpp, I'd consider using [Neils Lohmann's json library](https://github.com/nlohmann/json) instead. For a quick demo:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

#include "nlohmann/json.hpp"

std::string a = R"(
[
    {
        "city":"Lisbon",
        "name":"Shannon Ward",
        "job":"Ambulatory Nurse",
        "email":"Shannon_Ward6180@6ijur.works",
        "salary":"2308593.84555454"
    },
    {
        "city":"Lancaster",
        "name":"Kurt Hopkinson",
        "job":"Lecturer",
        "email":"Kurt_Hopkinson235@nb44i.digital",
        "salary":"8564088.47550575"
    }
]
)";

std::string b = R"(
[
    {
        "city":"Glendale",
        "name":"John Yates",
        "job":"Accountant",
        "email":"John_Yates1660@gkvds.store",
        "salary":"9003114.81075051"
    },
    {
        "city":"Sacramento",
        "name":"Camila Wallace",
        "job":"Budget Analyst",
        "email":"Camila_Wallace8030@3wbkp.site",
        "salary":"1287392.46738351"
    }
])";

int main() {

    using json = nlohmann::json;

    json ja = json::parse(a);
    json jb = json::parse(b);

    std::copy(jb.begin(), jb.end(), std::back_inserter(ja));

    std::cout << std::setw(5) << ja;
}
```

The result is what you'd expect: a single JSON array containing all four objects.

That said, given that the files are apparently fairly large, if you're really absolutely certain they contain exactly what's expected (a single JSON array in each, which should just be concatenated together) you may want to just copy the first file, delete the last character (the closing bracket), then copy the second starting from the second character (to skip its opening bracket). This is undoubtedly going to be a lot faster, and it's pretty easy to do with minimal memory usage as well.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/M9xzPdvx6

Comment: Thanks @Jerry, I am using jsoncpp because in many articles it is said that jsoncpp is more performance oriented than other libraries, here I might be wrong because I am beginner in this.

Comment: @AkashRajawat: That doesn't match most benchmarks I've seen. For example: https://github.com/miloyip/nativejson-benchmark/blob/master/sample/conformance_overall_Result.png, shows rapidjson (among others) in the lead, nlohmann JSON 4% slower, and jsoncpp 15% slower. Most other benchmarks I've seen roughly agree: nlohmann json is *extremely* close to as fast as you can get (and still generally the easiest to use).

Comment: Thanks for sharing that @JerryCoffin; actually I was following this article https://medium.com/ml2b/a-guide-to-json-using-c-a48039124f3a      and honestly I started with it because I liked its documentation. But, I'll try others libraries too.

Comment: @AkashRajawat: I get a little concerned when an article makes a bald pronouncement like that, without (as far as I can see) no attempt at providing data to back it up. That's not to say it's necessarily entirely wrong, but at best it's hard to be sure how much it means.